# Losing newlines when reading from stdin

Tags: bash

I have been beating my head up about this.
I wanted to loop over a multiline string character by character in bash but was loosing all newlines. First thing I did when i didn't find any obvious error was to run `shellcheck` on it, it seemed fine with the program.

*script.sh*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

transform_single() {
        if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
                echo 'Error: illegal number of args' 1>&2
        fi

        equation=''
        delim0=0
        delim="$1"

        while IFS= read -rn1 c; do
                if [[ $delim0 -eq 0 ]] && [[ "$c" == "$delim" ]]; then
                        delim0=1
                        equation=''
                elif [[ $delim0 -ne 0 ]] && [[ "$c" == "$delim" ]]; then
                        delim0=0
                        echo -n "$equation" | texmath
                elif [[ $delim0 -ne 0 ]]; then
                        equation="$equation$c"
                else
                        echo -n "$c"
                fi
        done
}

transform_single '$'
```

*input.txt:*

```
<newlines>
<newlines>
# Hello world!
<newlines>
This is a test string.
<newlines>
```

*invocation:*

```
bash script.sh < input.txt
```

*output:*

```
# Hello world!This is a test string.
```

*excepted output:*

The same as in the input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working script**

```
#!/bin/bash

transform_single() {
    if (($# != 1)); then echo 'Error: illegal number of args' 1>&2; fi
    equation=''
    delim0=0
    delim="$1"
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' -n 1 c; do
        if ((delim0 == 0)) && [[ "$c" == "$delim" ]]; then
            delim0=1
            equation=''
        elif ((delim0 != 0)) && [[ "$c" == "$delim" ]]; then
            delim0=0
            echo -n "$equation" | texmath
        elif ((delim0 != 0)); then
            equation="$equation$c"
        else
            echo -n "$c"
        fi
    done
}

transform_single '$'
```

**The issue is that you must set a delimiter to read, a null character, to preserve line feed.**

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, can you explain why a delim of zero does the trick?